# Input non-printable ascii characters into scanf

Tags: c, linux

So I've seen these two questions:

- [Input string with non printable chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18945448/input-string-with-non-printable-chars)
- [Inputting Non ASCII characters to scanf("%s")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15123963/inputting-non-ascii-characters-to-scanfs)

And unfortunately these did not provide me for an answer I've needed
let's say I'm dependent within some output of a certain program and can't tell for sure which values I need to enter ahead of program's execution, I'd rather enter some input for example for this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char a[10] = {0};
    printf("\n----------- %x\n", (unsigned int) a); 
    scanf("%s", a);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10;  i++)
        printf("%d\n", (int) a[i]);
}
```

as an example, I'm waiting after the printf within the following program has reached, then

input -> some input containing non-printable ascii characters

program output-> 04
08
01
05
02
10
09
12
02
02 (All these are values of non-printable ascii characters)

and again I'm looking for a way to enter them **directly**

- **I'm not looking for a way to do this by implementing some
  functionality within my code, my code is given as an example of a
  program**
- **When saying during runtime, I mean after the program has started running - hence the prints within my program have reached**
- I apologize if this was unclaer

Comment: One of the answers gives: `printf '\x08\xDE\xAD' | yourprogram`. That is entered during runtime as you require. Please clarify why it is not acceptable for you so that the right solution can be given.

Comment: This isn't runtime as well, printf '\x088\xDE\xAD' runs first then entered into stdin as the input for my_program, my point is that for example my output is dependent of the prints within my_program hence it's not acceptable @kaylum

Comment: The problem you will have is depending on the shell you are using.  In a bash shell, you could use `echo -e "\x04"` to type in the ASCII code 4.  You won't be able to just type in 4 or something similar.

Comment: It's not that complicated, please read my question, I can't enter my input BEFORE THE PROGRAM RUNS I'm dependent of the prints within my program hence I must enter it during the runtime of the program (after the prints within my program were reached)

Comment: @DrPrItay Then do what @MarkTolonen suggested in the answer below. `scanf` is not designed to work with binary data and escape characters. You have to implement this functionality yourself.

Comment: when saying runtime I mean after the program has started executing, - after prints are reached for exampe, @kaylum

Comment: @EugeneSh. I'm looking for a way of doing that without implementing my own functionallity, perhaps posting my code here is useless, as I'm not looking for a way to change my code, I just gave it as an example of some program which I would be required to do such a thing

Comment: So it is not possible. Would that answer suffice?

Comment: No as I know it is possible, (usage of ctrl  + shift + u ) that unfortunately doesn't work fully for me @EugeneSh.

Comment: @EugeneSh. look at Barmar's answer, it is possible

Comment: What will you do if you want to enter `\0x00` or `\n`?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character @EugeneSh. I'd use barmar's method for control characters and ctrl + shift + u for other non-printable ascii values

Comment: It doesn't matter how you enter it, by hitting "enter" or inputting some control character representing `\n` or a whitespace, it will eventually terminate your string reading, because it is how `scanf` works. To emphasize, what will be your input to get the code snippet to print the code for a whitespace (i.e. 0x20) ?

Comment: again, try ctrl + shift + u with hex value or the control characters, worked for me @EugeneSh.

Comment: You are telling me that you were able to get from the snippet above the output `"32 32 32"` by hitting `ctrl + shift + u 20` three times, for example? Unfortunately I can't test it myself, but I would believe you if you say so.

Comment: Yup, exactly what I'm saying :) @EugeneSh.

Comment: @DrPrItay `scanf("%s", a);` does not save space characters in `a`.  [This is suspicious](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41683969/input-non-printable-ascii-characters-into-scanf#comment70566096_41683969) that OP was able to get `"32 32 32"`.  Request OP's clarification.

Comment: @chux This what is making me doubt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux you can type <kbd>Control-v</kbd> before a control character to enter it literally. So to type the character with code `0x04`, type <kbd>Control-v</kbd><kbd>Control-d</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks, this is the exact answer I was looking for

Comment: What about ascii characters with value bigger than 127?, I'm failing to use ctrl shit u combination for ascii values such as 137 (0x89)

Comment: It depends on the terminal emulator if it provides a way to type those characters.

Comment: On ubuntu? @Barmar

Comment: On any operating system. If you can't get the terminal emulator to send the code, then the application can't read it from interactive input.